# Cloud 9: PHP7 cURL not working

Tags: php, curl, cloud9-ide, php-extension, php-7

Not sure why this isn't working in c9... but

[image]

It's really strange because i have installed php5-curl, but i do have php7.0.9, is there a php7-curl?

I have tried apt-get php-curl, php7-curl, php7.0-curl.... and none of them work.
All I get is:

E: Unable to locate package php70-curl 
for all of them.

I also updated apt-get.....

SO am i missing something?

Answer (score 1):

PHP 5 extensions do not work with PHP 7. As far as I know, if you compile PHP 7 with `--with-curl` in the configure command, it will just compile it in.

Are you running Ubuntu? If you are, then are you running 16.04 or newer? In 16.04, there's a package called php7.0-curl in the Ubuntu repositories. http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/php7.0-curl

If you are on Ubuntu and on a release earlier than 16.04, I would suggest upgrading. If you are not on Ubuntu, then which distribution are you on?

EDIT: After creating an account on Cloud9, I found that the PHP template is running Ubuntu 14.04 with PHP 5.5. Did you change this?

Comment: I did, i switched it with phpbrew to 7.0.9 in Ubuntu 14.04. Any work around on this?

Comment: https://github.com/phpbrew/phpbrew#extra-configure-options Try adding `-- --with-curl=shared` or `-- --with-curl`.

Comment: That was a close solution... but looking into their extensions a bit further and boom

phpbrew ext install curl. Problem fixed!

Thanks for helping out!

Comment: Nice! Go ahead and write out your whole solution steps so you can mark it as the solution and then other people can upvote it and learn from it.